# How does Microsoft DOS SET command translate into C#?

Tags: .net, command-line, process, cgi, exe

I am invoking an exe file (which is essentially a cgi script) with using the .net `Process` and `ProcessInfo` classes. I need to be able to set some environment variables before I call `Process.Start`.

If I was to go the DOS Command line route I would be doing this:

```
 SET UrlString=http://mytest
```

How does the SET command translate to .Net in the context of using the `Process` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [StartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) property of process object and add variables to [EnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx) dictionary

```
var prc = new Process();
prc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["UrlString"] = "http://mytest";
```

*update: Be sure to see comment by sixlettervariables (tnx!), and set UseShellExecute to false

Comment: [Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx): *You must set the `UseShellExecute` property to `false` to start the process after changing the `EnvironmentVariables` property.*